# Why does my SQL code throw a conversion error?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I am beginner so it will be nice when you can explain it to me.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) = 2017 THEN 'AKTUALNE'
       WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) < 2015 THEN KIEROWCA2_DATA
       WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) = 2016 THEN KIEROWCA1_DATA
       WHEN KIEROWCA1_DATA IS NULL THEN GETDATE()
       WHEN STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA is NULL THEN 'TUTAJ BYŁA WARTOŚĆ PUSTA'
    END
FROM 
    POJAZDY
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single type of the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression [*ref*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  My guess is that the two fields specified are not strings.  If not, the `GETDATE()` will throw everything off. 
 Strings will get converted to that type.

So, add *explicit* conversion:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) = 2017 THEN 'AKTUALNE'
             WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) < 2015 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), KIEROWCA2_DATA
             WHEN YEAR(STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA) = 2016 THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), KIEROWCA1_DATA
             WHEN KIEROWCA1_DATA IS NULL THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), GETDATE())
             WHEN STAN_LICZNIKA_DATA is NULL THEN 'TUTAJ BYŁA WARTOŚĆ PUSTA'
        END)
FROM POJAZDY
```

[See Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you :) Now it is simple